# Are remote sex toys allowed?

Tags: sex

As-salamu alaykum,

My wife and I live are in different countries, and I have been advised that
using sex toys is permissible if used by one's partner.

My question is: Can we use a remote-controlled sex toy, where I have control
at times and she also has control at other times? Does this fall under
acceptable use, or is it considered masturbation?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

What is between wife and husband should be confined to them only and a third party like online server, camera, toys etc is intruding on privacy and can get leaked causing much problem for both of you. In one hadith it is given like this

> Abu Sa'id al-Khudri (Allah he pleased with him) reported that Allah's
> Messenger (may peace be upoin him) said: The most wicked among the
> people in the eye of Allah on the Day of judgment is the men who goes
> to his wife and she comes to him, and then he divulges her secret. https://sunnah.com/muslim:1437a